# TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable, how to display time using a function

Tags: python

I want to use the function datetime to display the time, but I am not able to. I kept getting 'TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable'.Can someone please advise me how to solve this error.

```
from _datetime import datetime
class purchasDateTime:
    def __init__(self, datetime):
        self._datetime = datetime

    @property
    def datetime(self):
        return self._datetime

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Date&Time: {:%#d %b %Y %H:%M}'.format(self._datetime)


def main():
    t1 = purchasDateTime(datetime(2019,4,8,12,45))
    print(t1)
    print('Pickup time:',t1.datetime())

main()
```

The result I want to get is "Pickup time: 12:45 PM"

Comment: `print('Pickup time:', t1.datetime)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
print('Pickup time:', t1.datetime.strftime('%H:%M %p'))
```

It's a typo, because since you have a `@property` above your function, that function doesn't need to be called, just use it like a direct attribute, that's why you need to use the above code, your code should work fine now.

That said, i would recommend you to read:

> [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Comment: Hi @U9-Forward, is there a way to get the time only??

Answer (score 1):

```
@property
def datetime(self):
    return self._datetime
```

The purpose of the `@property` decorator is so you can refer to this as a *property* instead of a *function*, i.e. `t1.datetime` instead of `t1.datetime()`.

TLDR: take off the parentheses `()`.